# Rails4 : Create a table at runtime Or Other better Architecture pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-schema, multi-tenant

I am creating a Rails app for a client that lets them connect data generating devices to the app and perform analysis.  The Device either POST some data to app or the APP GETS it from a url.

The device can generate a lot of data (250M+ records/rows in a year) and  data generation rate might grow.

There is no inter-device analytics. Hence, I am thinking of partitioning the data by limiting 1 device to 1 table.

```
Here are few things I need:

 1. Client should be able to add a new device through a form. 
 2. This should create a new table, say device1_data at runtime and also run appropriate migrations.
```

In a way it's similar to a multi-tenant architecture.
What's a good way to achieve this in Rails4.1? (deployed on Heroku)

Comment: Does the data have to be stored in a relational database? Have you considered a schema free alternative like MongoDB? I would definitely consider it since it makes it really easy to group data into embedded  collections and has good performance for huge data sets. Might be a good alternative to hacking ActiveRecord into doing something it's not really built for (dynamic tables at runtime).

Comment: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Max. They need to do selects and aggregations (Sum etc) on the data. I think they would need to do more than that so I am thinking about creating reports for them.  One thing to note is that we are archiving anything that's more than a month.  I will take a look at what kind of operations could be done using mongoid

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: [Be cautious](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/07/19/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-mongodb/) about using MongoDB instead.